# What is a type extends in a class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, types

Please can you clarify what is the meaning of this notation in Typescript and where to find documentation? Is typeA an alias of typeB? Does typeA extends also typeC and typeD? Does myClass "see" typeA inside itself? Thanks.

```
classe myClass<
    typeA extends typeB = Unknown
> extends anotherClass<
    typeC,
    typeD
>
```

Comment: That's a combination of https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html (see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes, it's an ES6 feature) and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing here is a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) which extends another generic class.

`typeB`, `typeC`, `typeC`, and `Unknown` are all known, pre-defined types.  `typeA` is a variable. (The example could make that distinction a lot more clear.)

> Does myClass "see" typeA inside itself?

Yes!  `myClass` can use the type `typeA` for any of its methods or other internal typings.

> Does typeA extends also typeC and typeD?

No.  It might be true in some cases but it's not required.  `anotherClass` has two generic variables.  We are stating that our class `myClass` extends the version of `anotherClass` where those variables are set to `typeC` and `typeD`.  Again, `typeC` and `typeD` are known types.

> Is typeA an alias of typeB?

No, not always.  Our variable `typeA` must `extend` the known type `typeB`.  It could be `typeB` exactly or something that extends it.  It is ok to use `typeA` anywhere that requires `typeB` since we know that `typeA extends typeB`.

`Unknown` is the fallback value for the variable `typeA` is no type can be inferred. `Unknown` must also extend `typeB`.

Hopefully this example makes it more clear:

```
// AnotherClass depends on two generics which could be anything
class AnotherClass<DataType, KeyType> {
    // the generics are used here to determine the types of the instance variables
    data: DataType;
    key: KeyType;

    // the generic values for each instance will be determined by the arguments which are passed to the constructor
    constructor(data: DataType, key: KeyType) {
        this.data = data;
        this.key = key;
    }
}

// MyInterface is some sort of known type
interface MyInterface {
    myKey: string;
}

// MyClass has one generics value Name which can be a specific string or just `string`
// it extends AnotherClass where `DataType` is `MyInterface` and `KeyType` is `string`
class MyClass<Name extends string = string> extends AnotherClass<MyInterface, string> {
    
    name: Name;

    constructor(name: Name, data: MyInterface) {
        // must call superclass AnotherClass's constructor
        super(data, name);
        
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/KWzb4W)